# Change order status from pending to processing in Admin

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, sales-order, order-status, order-history

I'm not much experienced in Magento. I'm working on a legacy Magento codebase where we use Magento 1.7.

Currently the status is changed from pending to processing using API calls. And it works perfectly. But I've got a requirement where we need to achieve the same from Magento Admin panel itself.

I've read in a lot of places that the status can be changed by adding a comment in order page. But the comment dropdown is limited to showing only `pending` option. I've looked at the code and I can't find the code for fetching order statuses (`getStateStatuses`) being overwritten anywhere.

I'm not sure what other details are needed to debug this. If you can ask me in comments, I can add the details.